# Java Date confusion

Tags: java, date

I am really very confused about dates.

I have a web application which has a backend on Java. I have a date field which has no time information. I write this info to DB using **hibernate**. Its definition is

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
```

Actually these are basic infos. Here is my problem.

I run java on `UTC(GMT+0)` timezone but client timezone is `GMT+3`.

A user picks a day (*let's say* `10.12.2016 (dd.MM.yyyy)`). On client side this day represented as `10.12.2016 00:00 GMT+3`. After this user wants to save this date.

This date comes to my backend as `09.12.2016 21:00 GMT+0`. I want to save this date without timeinfo. So java code saves data as `09.12.2016`. (which corresponds to *`09.12.2016 00:00 GMT+0`*)

Now user wants to see what s/he saved. Java reads date as `09.12.2016 00:00 GMT+0` and client gets this date as  `09.12.2016 03:00 GMT+3`. At the end, the user sees date as `09.12.2016` but s/he saved this date as `10.12.2016`.

So the user sees the day, one day before s/he actually saved.

I want to keep data as `TemporalType.DATE` and want to show user the correct date.

How can I solve this problem? I keep digging for 2 days on Google but I could not find a reasonable explanation.

**NOTE**:** My users can be different timezones not only on `GMT+3`. Please consider this situation.

Comment: You should use timestamps, and store UTC time in your actual database.  This is the only way to get the day boundary right.  Actually, many databases do not even store timezone information.

Comment: Well this seems logical but consider a user which on GMT+2. This user see date as 09.10.2016 (because date will be 09.10.2016 23:00). Is this a normal case or should I do some arrangements :/

Comment: Is a timezone relevant without a time?  What do the dates represent.  Your user will enter a date and you are effectively changing it to another time by truncating the time.  At a minimum the client will have to send their current timezone in case they enter the date in one timezone then move to a different timezone. Then convert your GMT timezone to the client's timezone supplied on their request.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that, if your application is aware of client's GMT you are receiving the GMT position from request so I won't go deep into this point because it would be needed further information about what your application does.

Once you have request's GMT info, you only have to do this:

```
Date databaseDate = database's date (you said you were working in GMT and it was also stored in GMT 0 so no further transformation is required)

//As you said you are working in GMT 0 this will be the GMT of your calendar.
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

//As you know your GMT you only have to set it through this method
TimeZone clientTimezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1:00");

Date originalDate = inputCalendar.getTime();
calendar.setTimeZone(clientTimezone);

//This will return you the offset -positive or negative- of calendars time zone respect to UTC 0 - GMT 0 - in milliseconds
int offset = inputCalendar.getTimeZone().getOffset(originalDate.getTime());

//You get the database's date in milliseconds and add your offset to it. It can be positive or negative and the final result will the date transformed to your request's GMT
Date clientDate= (new Date(originalDate.getTime() + offset));
```

And it would be enough for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Several options available for you.

1. If you are working with Java 8 (or can switch to java 8) then new
   package `java.time` provides much more flexible date model and class
   [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) will give you precisely what you need.
2. If you work with java 7 or less I would sudjest to store your Date
   in DB as a String field. I.e. format your Date to String and save it
   that way to DB into varchar field. When you read it just parse it
   back to Date. This way your "10.12.2016" will remain such in any
   time zone without any additional trickery.
3. Finally, if you insist on keeping it as Date you might want to
   inforce that all your Dates are always stored in GMT+0 regardless of
   actiual location. This way user in the same location will always see
   the same date. But two users in different locations still might see
   the same field as a different dates

I would sugjest the 1st option if possible and if not then 2d. Third is would become more and more complex if your app is used by users in dfferent time zones.

Also you might find this article interesting: It is about converting a String of unknown format to Date: [Parsing any string to Date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman?trk=mp-reader-card)

Answer (score 0):

Some general info about your date-time issues, not Hibernate specific…

What time zone is the current default on your server should be irrelevant. Always specify your desired/expected time zone in your code by always passing the optional time zone argument. Discussed many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

```
LocalDate todayMontreal = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

A date-only value without time zone is indeed imprecise. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone. A few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still ‘yesterday’ in Montréal Canada. Discussed many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

If you want precision use a date-time with time zone. Discussed many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

```
ZonedDateTime todayMontrealStart = todayMontreal.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

…or…

```
ZonedDateTime todayMontrealStart = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

For storing data, make that time zone UTC. The `Instant` class is always in UTC by default.

```
Instant instant = todayMontrealStart.toInstant();
```

Your JDBC driver and/or database may do this for you. With JDBC 4.2 and later, pass java.time objects via `getObject` and `setObject`, otherwise fall back to java.sql types for exchanging data with database. Discussed many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and `.Calendar`. Now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Discussed many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

Specifically, you should search Stack Overflow for the classes LocalDate, Instant, OffsetDateTime, and ZonedDateTime.

Bonus tip: when exchanging date-time values as text such as between your client and server, use ISO 8601 standard formats. Discussed many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.